# ERROR TypeError: You provided 'null' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angularfire, angular-ng-if

I searched everywhere for an answer but I couldn't get out this issue.
I found that many people are having this issues with Observables in Angular but usually it was just a syntax error. I tried many things (I will list them below) but I'm confused. I don't know why it does like this.

**ERROR:**

> ERROR TypeError: You provided 'null' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

That's not a functionality error. In fact, it works perfectly with my expectations, but it throws an error to the console.

**EXPECTATION:**
It's just an ngIf directive that manages the view of a menu content. If the user is logged, it should view certain menu-items (for ex. 'My profile', etc...), if not, it should only see 'Login' and 'Signup' buttons. It actually works this kind of system, but I receive a console error.

**WHAT I TRIED:**
Googling around I tried many things. The one listed below are only few of them, but at some point I was just trying without knowing really how to solve the problem.

In the first try (which I will not list here because it was pretty long), I tried to switchMap the angular fire auth state to get the logged status, then I setted this.appUser$ to this.userService.get(user.uid), to return user data from the database. This will be the final result, but after getting the error I simplified by a lot the code to find out what can be the issue with that, hoping that it was easier. In fact, I didn't solved anything in 3 days of tries.

1. > navbar.component.html

```
<mat-menu #userMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent >
    <div class="menuContent" *ngIf="(appUser$ | async) as user; else notLoggedMenuitems">
      <div mat-menu-item>
        <div class="row no-gutters ml-2 mr-2">
          <div class="col-auto"><img [src]="user.photoURL" class="user-profile-img" alt="Profile image"></div>
          <div class="col"><p class="mat-body-strong mb-0 ml-3" style="line-height: 350%;"><b>{{ user.displayName }}</b></p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <mat-divider class="mt-2"></mat-divider>
      <div mat-menu-item>...</div>
      <div mat-menu-item>...</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <div mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">Logout</div>
    </div>

    <ng-template #notLoggedMenuitems>
      <div mat-menu-item routerLink="/auth/login">Login</div>
      <div mat-menu-item routerLink="/auth/signup">Signup</div>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

1. > navbar.component.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  appUser$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
    this.appUser$ = this.auth.user;
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }

}
```

2. > navbar.component.html
   > I changed the ngIf directive to the one below, removing the else block. I tried even with other operators like " ! " and so on, but nothing changed...

```
*ngIf="(appUser$ | async)"
```

2. > navbar.component.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  appUser$: Observable<firebase.User> = this.auth.user;

  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

  ngOnInit(): any {
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }

}
```

**CONCLUSION:**
How can I do this? I don't know why typescript throws this error.

**UPDATE 1:**
Updated navbar.component.html

```html
<mat-menu #userMenu="matMenu">
  <ng-template matMenuContent >
    <div class="menuContent" *ngIf="(appUser$ | async) as user; else notLoggedMenuitems">
      <div mat-menu-item>
        <div class="row no-gutters ml-2 mr-2">
          <div class="col-auto"><img [src]="user.details.imgUrl" class="user-profile-img" alt="Profile image"></div>
          <div class="col"><p class="mat-body-strong mb-0 ml-3" style="line-height: 350%;"><b>{{ user.name }}</b></p></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <mat-divider class="mt-2"></mat-divider>
      <ng-container *ngIf="user.roles.admin">
        <div mat-menu-item><mat-icon>local_bar</mat-icon>Manage Drinks</div>
          <div mat-menu-item><mat-icon>note_add</mat-icon>Add Drinks</div>
          <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </ng-container>
      <div mat-menu-item><mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>My Profile</div>
      <div mat-menu-item><mat-icon>wine_bar</mat-icon>My Drinks</div>
      <div mat-menu-item><mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>Wishlist</div>
      <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      <div mat-menu-item (click)="logout()">Logout</div>
    </div>

    <ng-template #notLoggedMenuitems>
      <div mat-menu-item routerLink="/auth/login">Login</div>
      <div mat-menu-item routerLink="/auth/signup">Signup</div>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
</mat-menu>
```

Updated navbar.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthenticationService } from './../../../auth/authentication/authentication.service';
import { User } from './../../../auth/authentication/models/user.model';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  appUser$: Observable<User>;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private auth: AngularFireAuth) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): any {
    this.appUser$ = this.authService.user$;
    this.appUser$.subscribe(res => console.log('in app user: ', res));
  }

  logout(): void {
    this.auth.signOut();
  }

}
```

Updated authentication.service.ts

```js
private initUser(): void {
  this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.db.doc$<User>(`users/${user.uid}`);
      } else {
        return undefined;
      }
    })
  );
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Updated authentication.service.ts

```js
private initUser(): void {
  this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return this.db.doc$<User>(`users/${user.uid}`);
      } else {
        return new Observable<User>();
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Now I don't see the error anymore. But the user image doesn't shows well... I don't know if that's a good method to do things though.

Comment: are you sure the error is about the `*ngIf`

Comment: did you verify that `auth.user` is returning a value, and that the type is compatible with `firebase.User`?

Comment: This kind of error happens when you use higher observables combined with operators like switchMap, mergeMap, etc. Those operators expect to return an observable which you did not since you are returning null at some point in your code.
May be that `this.auth.user` return simply null and you get this error because of the pipe async in the template.

Comment: Thanks guys, that helps a bit. Unfortunately I tried  to go back to the various services but I can't find anything.

@ Elmehdi no, I don't think it's caused by ngIf actually.
@ PMO1948 it's returning firebase.User or null.
@QuentinFonck this.auth it's AngularFireAuth, so it should be optimized I guess. It's an official library of firebase. Unfortunately I don't know how to manage this error. Any ideas on debugging?

PS: I'm also available to do a call on skype or something else to share the screen.

Comment: I've another question. How can I return an empty user?

Comment: Now I edited my code and it looks like this:
[**navbar.component.html**](http://prntscr.com/vhd6jx)
[**navbar.component.ts**](http://prntscr.com/vhd8bw)
[**authentication.service.ts**](https://prnt.sc/vhd95w)

Comment: With this, in the authentication service I can now return something else instead of null. But I don't know what type of observable I should return

Comment: @PietroLungarini I know, I use angularfire too in my project. But I don't use auth.user, I use the auth.authState to know if have a user log in or not. When you subscribe to `this.appUser$` in your component, does it return anything ? Try to do this in your onInit() method: `this.appUser$.subscribe(res => console.log('in app user: ', res))`

Comment: @QuentinFonck i have tried what you said. See here the console logs: https://prnt.sc/vhfhlq . This is what I have in my component.ts : http://prntscr.com/vhfj4p . I haven't changed anything from my latest screenshots. By the way, even with authState I get the same error.

Comment: well, I just check your authentication.service that you 've created and your use of switchMap is wrong. Could you update your question with your current code AND with the service your are using to check what's going on. We cannot keep track of your code with screenshots. I would be able to give you a proper answer with this.

Comment: Ok I updated the code @QuentinFonck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you almost got it.
What is not correct is the way you handle your user$ in your service. You should always return an observable in a switchMap operator.
To handle the case where there's no user login, you can use `of()`. It's an observable that emits the value passed in param and complete right after that.
Regarding the database your using, are you using firestore or the realtime database ?
To request your data, in both cases, you need to end your call with valueChanges to return an observable.
I asume you are using firestore since you called the doc method:

```js
private initUser(): void {
  this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        // return an observable<User>
        return this.db.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`).valueChanges();
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Try this, it should work.

Comment: I see that of() it's deprecated, or not?

Comment: By the way, Yup! I'm using firestore, but I implemented a custom service (this.db) which replicates some boiler plate code. So this.db.doc$<User> returns an observable :)

Comment: By the way, besides that it tells me that of() it's deprecated, it works amazingly! Thanks so much <3

Comment: Of is not deprecated. It should be `import { of} from 'rxjs';`. What do you have?

Comment: Mmh that's weird. Hovering the mouse on the { of } import shows this tooltip on VS code.
https://prnt.sc/vhu6kx

Comment: That's the scheduler argument in the `of` function that is deprecated, not the function itself :) . Of is safe to use. VsCode usually cross functions name when they are deprecated. You can alt + click the `of` in the import call to see the function definition.
That's a good way to check for docs and see what is allowed.

Comment: Oh! Thanks so much :) That's clear. Thank for the help Quentin :) Have an amazing day